Удалила мышь и клавиатуру, перезапуск не помог, комп не видит, что делать?
Я зашла в "Диспетчер устройств", открыла вкладку "контроллеры USB", в которой был перечень подключенных к компьютеру usb-устройств, и удалила мышь и клавиатуру (intel(R)... Usb....).
Чисто теоретически после перезагрузки компьютер должен был обновиться и распознать заново эти устройства. Этого не произошло, я вижу только экран, но мышь и клавиатура не принимаются через порт системного блока, вернее индикатор горит, но курсора на экране нет, мышь и клавиатура не действуют. Биос не открывается при загрузке, но и там я бы не могла использовать клавиатуру и мышь. Что делать?

Биос не открывается при загрузке у разных биосов разный хот-кей входа:(delete, f2, f8...) но и там я бы не могла использовать клавиатуру и мышь только если сами устройства(клаво-мышь) повреждены, или их кабель, иль гнезда в которых они находятся(в случае с гнездами, при втыкании их в другие - они должны ожить), биосу без разницы если ли у ОС драйвера, он и без накопителя работать и может и должен. кстати, стоит уточнить: зачем\почему изначально удаляли их в диспетчере устройств? если из-за того что они перестали подавать признаки жизни, то вероятнее всего они просто сломаны.

Чисто теоретически, я бы попробовал подключить еще какое нибудь устройство, например телефон через usb кабель, дальше попробовать заново переподключить мышь и клаву. Если не помогает, то например купил бы bluetooth мышь и подключил бы ее. Потом бы уже смотрел.
Также, нужно видеть, что происходит при перезагрузке системы. Попробуйте войти в биос и посмотреть там, инициалицированы устройства или нет.
